# How to get count based on some common words in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a column having almost same lines except for few words.
So I want to get some common words or pattern in this column of text. I have provided sample input, as my data is huge.

```
u=data.frame(text=c("you can find details on sunday",
                    "you may find details on sunday",
                    "you will find details on saturday",
                    "where can I get my personal details on portal",
                    "where to see personal details"),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

For all of these, I am getting count as 1. But I want to combine counts if they are having common words inorder to get sum of `count`.

Expected result in a dataframe with 2 columns - `text` and `count`:
`"you can find details"` - count should come 3
`"my personal details"` - count should come as 2

Comment: How detailed the answer should be? Do you need counts of word "you" (3 counts) or "on" (4 counts)?

Answer (score 0):

A `tidyverse` solution to your problem using `str_count` from the [stringr package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/stringr.html):

```
library(tidyverse)

str <- c("find details","personal details")

u %>% 
  mutate( find =  stringr::str_count(text, str[1]),
          personal =  stringr::str_count(text, str[2]),
          )
```

Output:

```
                                              text find personal
1                you can find details on sunday    1        0
2                you may find details on sunday    1        0
3             you will find details on saturday    1        0
4 where can I get my personal details on portal    0        1
5                 where to see personal details    0        1
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, my file is huge, hence how can I determine what to write in str ?? Any pattern can you suggest?

Comment: the bigger your file, the more advisable it would be to create shorter strings to look for, i.e. just looking for all columns that have "where" or "personal" and then creating new variables based on these combinations (like a variable for all occurences where "where", "personal" and "details" came up. If your dataset is based on respondent's text boxes, I would also check for typing errors.

Comment: Suppose if it has names of person, how do I go about it?

Comment: if you interested in specific names, just extend `str` with any name and call it in your `mutate` call via `str[x]` . If you want to know if the text contains any name, you could get a list of (first) names and create a variable via `newvar = ifelse(text %in% name_of_your_namedf` .

Answer (score 0):

A `base R` solution would be to use `gregexpr/regmatches` for extracting the words based on the vector of words ('str1') and then assigning the `list` of vector into columns

```
u[c("find", "personal")] <- lapply(str1, function(x) 
             lengths(regmatches(u$text, gregexpr(x, u$text))))
u
#                                           text find personal
#1                you can find details on sunday    1        0
#2                you may find details on sunday    1        0
#3             you will find details on saturday    1        0
#4 where can I get my personal details on portal    0        1
#5                 where to see personal details    0        1
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("find details","personal details")
```